# Issue with seting up a pub/ sub implementation with Pubnub

Tags: javascript, api, publish-subscribe, pubnub, cryptocurrency

First off let me start by saying I am a web developer who is very new to the Blockchain space so I apologize in advance if I am missing something obvious. With that being said I am having issues implementing a broadcast transaction method into a cryptocurrency project I am working on. Every time I am able to successfully make transaction requests to my API and I am able to see the correct transaction pool on the main dev network, however my peer network does not see any new transactions until I restart it. I know this means my broadcast transaction implementation is missing something but I am not sure what I need to fix it.

please refer to the following images

[image: Dev port(left) Dev-peer(Right)]

[image: GET Request to API returns transaction]

[image: GET Request to dev-peer port does NOT return transaction]

[image: Dev-Peer port updates the transaction when the sync method is called after restarting the node]

Here is the code snippets for my pubsub implementation using PUBNUB

```
const CHANNELS = {
    TEST: "TEST",
    BLOCKCHAIN: "BLOCKCHAIN",
    TRANSACTION: "TRANSACTION"
};

class PubSub {
    constructor({blockchain, transactionPool}) {
        this.blockchain = blockchain;
        this.transactionPool = transactionPool;
        this.pubnub = new PubNub(credentials); // defined above but omitted for obvious reasons
        this.pubnub.subscribe({channels: Object.values(CHANNELS)}); // defined in channels object
        this.pubnub.addListener(this.listener());
    };

    listener() {
        return {
            message: messageObject => {
                const { channel, message } = messageObject;

                console.log(`Message received. Channel: ${channel}. Message: ${message}`);

                const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

                switch(channel) {
                    case CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN:
                        this.blockchain.replaceChain(parsedMessage);
                        break;
                    case CHANNELS.TRANSACTION: 
                        this.transactionPool.setTransaction(parsedMessage);
                        break;
                    default: 
                        return;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    publish({channel, message}) {
        this.pubnub.unsubscribe(channel, () => {
            this.pubnub.publish(channel, message, () => {
                this.pubnub.subscribe(channel);
            });
        });
 
    }

    broadcastChain() {
        this.publish({
            channel: CHANNELS.BLOCKCHAIN,
            message: JSON.stringify(this.blockchain.chain)
        })
    }

    broadcastTransaction(transaction) {
        this.publish({
            channel: CHANNELS.TRANSACTION,
            message: JSON.stringify(transaction)
        });
    }
    };
```

And here is the snippets for where the broadcastTransaction method is called

```
const pubsub = new PubSub({blockchain, transactionPool});

    let transaction = transactionPool.existingTransaction({inputAddress: wallet.publicKey}); // Creates global binding

// Sends transaction to the network
app.post("/api/transact", (req, res) => {
    const {amount, recipient} = req.body;


    try {
        if(transaction) {
            transaction.update({senderWallet: wallet, recipient, amount });
        } else {
            transaction = wallet.createTransaction({recipient, amount});
        }
    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(400).json({type: "error", message: error.message});
    };

    transactionPool.setTransaction(transaction);

    pubsub.broadcastTransaction(transaction); // Calls broadcastTransaction from pubsub class (does not work for peers)

    res.json({type: "success", transaction});
});
```

I tried to be as specific as possible but If I missed anything please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be nice to get some of the data from the screenshots as text and can you explain what you are observing, and not observing (but expect to observe) when you say: "Every time I am able to successfully make transaction requests to my API and I am able to see the correct transaction pool on the main dev network, however my peer network does not see any new transactions until I restart it."?

Comment: You can also add `logVerbosity: true` to your `new PubNub` to show verbose logs from PN SDK. Do that and post that text file, too.

Comment: Any progress on producing logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input. logging helped me realize that my dev and peer ports were not subscribed when starting up the nodes. I added the following method to the PubSub class and was able to sync both the dev and peer ports

```
subscribeToChannels() {
    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: [Object.values(CHANNELS)]
    });
  }
```